# How to apply same settings to different figures in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I want to apply this changes to all of my figures:

```
set(gcf,'color','w');
box off;
set(gca,'FontSize',13,'fontWeight','bold')
set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'FontSize',13,'fontWeight','bold')
```

How do I do that without the need of repeating myself like this:

```
figure(1);
set(gcf,'color','w');
figure(2);
set(gcf,'color','w');
```

Comment: if there is lots of figure, you can consider using loop?

Comment: The function `set` can take an array of handle on which to apply the property. This would work fine for your second code snippet: `set([1 2],'Color','w')`. If you have more figure, just collect all the handles in an array when you create them, then call `set` on the whole lot. It will work for other properties as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it only for one session or a script, add this to the top of your script (or at the matlab command line before you plot anything):

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureColor', 'w');
```

or

```
set(groot, 'DefaultFigureColor', 'w');
```

This eliminates the need for multiple `set` commands.
If you want this to hold for every matlab session you should consider putting it into your `startup.m` file. Type

```
which startup
```

to locate your startup file or create one if it doesn't exist. Check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) for the other properties you might want to set defaults for.

Comment: How about box off and the other sets I added?

Comment: Use `set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontWeight', 'bold')` and  `set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontSize', 13)` respectively. Unfortunately, `box off` is modified each time you call the `plot` command, as is explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79229-set-0-defaultaxesbox-off-is-not-honored-by-plot).

Comment: I always forget about the root object and I never knew about the `groot` commend.  Good tips, thanks! +1